# Is there a "there exists" quantifier in QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

There is the `forAll` quantifier that returns a property which checks if all test cases pass. Is there a way to define a  "there exists" quantifier that returns a property which checks it at least one test case passes?

Comment: Problem is that the library usually generates random values. So it is possible it will take *ages* before you find a value that satisfies the condition. Furthermore if the test itself is not true. It will never end generating values.

Comment: Yes, but it can still be useful if you're confident that there are many test cases that satisfy the condition. I'm looking for a property that will stop generating values as soon as the condition is satisfied once.

Comment: That would allow us to write, for example, propositions like "There exists an n such that the property is true for all m > n".

Comment: But say you have a property: `length a < 0`. So the length should be less than `0`. It is clear it will never be satisfied. So the tests will get stuck into an infinite loop where they will keep generating lists in the hope one of them will have a lenght less than `0`. Now you cannot make a distinction between: "not satisfied because the condition is rare", or "unsatisifiable".

Comment: Why not stop generating cases after 100 tries like with forAll? The same argument could be used against `forAll` anyway: you cannot make a distinction between "satisfied because the counter example is rare" and "true".

Comment: yeah but the outcome is different: if a counterexample is rare: the program will report "satisfied", whereas if an example in an exists is rare, it will report "false". QuickCheck is optimistic: there is no guarantee - as with all unit tests - that a program is correct if the tests are satisifed. It however makes you more certain.

Comment: I don't get it. I need a "there exists" quantifier that generates tests until one passes and reports "satisfied" or "false/not satisfied" if a max number of tests are reached. I know that quickCheck can't work well with rare examples or counter examples, but it's useful anyway. I don't really understand if you're telling me "it's impossible with quickCheck as it is". Is this so? Or are you arguing about whether it's a good thing to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Testing existence by enumeration would be more reliable: [SmallCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck), [LeanCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/leancheck), [FEAT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/testing-feat).

If you must use random generation there are some indirect ways in QuickCheck.

---

[`expectFailure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:expectFailure) seems like a good candidate for negation. However it isn't quite it, as it isn't involutive so you must negate the property in other ways, like `not`, if your property is in fact boolean.

```
exists :: Gen a -> (a -> Bool) -> Property
exists gen prop = once $ expectFailure (forAll gen (not . prop))
```

This counts crashing as a failure though, which thus makes the test pass even though you might not expect it.

---

Existential quantification is kind of a disjunction, and QuickCheck has [`disjoin`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:disjoin). Just make a huge enough disjunction.

```
exists :: Gen a -> (a -> Property) -> Property
exists gen prop = once $ disjoin $ replicate 10000 $ forAll gen prop
```

But you get spammed with counterexamples when no good example is found.
Maybe it is better to rewrite the logic of `forAll` yourself to avoid the call to `counterexample`.

---

More simply you can always write your own property as a generator to get the proper quantification.

```
exists :: Gen a -> (a -> Bool) -> Property
exists gen prop = property (exists' 1000 gen prop)

exists' :: Int -> Gen a -> (a -> Bool) -> Gen Bool
exists' 0 _ _ = return False
exists' n gen prop = do
  a <- gen
  if prop a
    then return True
    else exists' (n - 1) gen prop
```

Doing this manually also has the property that if `prop` unexpectedly crashes, it is immediately reported as a failure, as opposed to the previous methods.

---

### EDIT

So if you only have a `(a -> Property)` instead of `(a -> Bool)` it seems much trickier to achieve a good result, because it's non-trivial to check whether a property succeeded. A proper way would be to mess with the internals of QuickCheck, probably something similar to `disjoin`. Here is a quick hack

- Use `mapResult` to silence the output of `disjoin` when no (counter)example was found.
- Override the size parameter because if your witnesses are non-trivial, they will not be found if the size is too small or too large.

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Property as P

-- Retry n times.
exists :: Testable prop => Int -> Gen a -> (a -> prop) -> Property
exists n gen prop =
  mapResult (\r -> r {P.reason = "No witness found.", P.callbacks = []}) $
  once $
  disjoin $
  replicate n $ do
    a <- gen
    return (prop a)

main = quickCheck $ exists 100
  (resize 5 arbitrary)
  (\x -> (x :: Integer) == 2)
```

Comment: Your third suggestion is close to what I'm looking for. But in order to combine it with `forAll`, for example to write `exists gen1 $ \a -> forAll gen2 ...`, exists would have to have signature `(Testable prop) => Gen a -> (a -> prop) -> Property`. I've trouble finding out how to do this reading QuickCheck's source code. Would you know how to do it?

Comment: I guess my example relies a lot on the property being simply boolean. If you have an abstract `prop` you can use `.||.` or `disjoin`, which ends up resembling what I suggested in the second example about not calling `counterexample`.

Comment: `once $ disjoin $ replicate 10000 $ do { a <- gen ; return (prop a) }`But as I said, it silences exceptions. It turns out you can use `mapResult` as suggested by Alexey Romanov to check for exceptions raised at the end of `disjoin`.

Comment: Your last suggestion seems to work but takes a long time and fills the console with empty lines. I've spent days on it but I still can't figure out how to do this properly. Could you rewrite your 3rd suggestion in your post so that it works with a Testable prop instead of a Bool? The whole problem I can't solve is how to check if `prop a` is a success of a failure.

Comment: I appended something that seems to work, still with `disjoin`. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a good way based on a pure generator (mainly because I'm not familiar enough with the internals of `Property`). Somehow `once` doesn't  have the effect I expected. Sorry if that answer is still unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if something like this exist in QuickCheck. Also not convinced it would be helpful, but that's another matter. Since we have:

```
∃ x . P x <=> ¬ ¬ ∃ x . P x <=> ¬ ∀ x . ¬ P x
```

I suppose you could set it up so your test-case tests the negation and if it fails it means you have your existential. HTH.

Comment: I've thought about that, but how do you take the negation of `forAll ...` in quickCheck? I've already tried `not (forAll gen prop)` but `forAll` returns a Property ant `not` expects a Bool.

Comment: @GuillaumeChérel You should be able to implement it using `mapResult`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#mapResult.